# File Upload Inside of MVC Html.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a view that has data we load through a ViewModel, this displays information about a project. I use `Html.BeginForm()` to create a form and then display all the data on the page. In the middle of `Html.BeginForm()` is my file upload control. It looks something like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    ... //Load other form data
    <p>1. Upload Data.</p>
    <div class="fileUploadContainer">
       <input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload"><button id="dataUpload" class="redButton">Upload</button>
    </div>
    ... //Load more form data
}
```

So my question is what is the best way for this upload function to work independently of the other form, obviously I cannot embed a form within a form. I created a seperate Action for this method in my controller called `UploadProjectData`, the regular form submits to its own controller action.

Comment: try http://www.uploadify.com/ may help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I supose you can try to use client javascript code to catch the File descriptor contained on your input type file, then, through an AJAX call, pass the file to your server and work with it.

Check this wonderful article on the matter for further info
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Anyway I'd get out of the form the input type file if I don't want it to be sent by the main form.